# scrollTop works only partially - it stops after 1-2 cm

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

For some reason `.scrollTop` works only partially. It starts scrolling and stops after 1-2 cm. It's a large page and container `#topdiv` is located at the top part of the page. All other functions - .prepend .hide .close works fine here. Console doesn't show any errors. I tried `.scrollTo` instead of `.scrollTop` - the same result.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('submit', '#saverepost', function (e) {
            var str = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/script.php",
                data: str,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#message').show();
                    $("#message").html('<img src="/loading.gif" />');
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    $.lbox.close();
                    $("#message").hide();
                    $("#posts").prepend(msg);
                    $("#topdiv").scrollTop(0);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: FYI you have 2 document ready handlers - you can safely remove one of them.

Comment: Could you post your html dom structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scroll the actual window you don't target a div

```
$("#topdiv").scrollTop(0);
```

If you want to scroll the entire page do this

```
$('html,body').scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: And what Rory McCrossan said, you have two document ready statements.

Comment: yes, with $('html,body') it works but not with #topdiv. I tried to remove secont document statement: $('html,body') and replaced it with : $('#saverepost').on('submit', function(e) { but it doesn't work.

Comment: You understood me wrong. This is how the final script should look like http://jsfiddle.net/4VpJN/

Comment: The form is in a modal window. If I remove the second "document" it sends a normal request instead of ajax call.

Comment: Try creating a Fiddle on jsfiddle.net and sharing it with us. Without the actual HTML i'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Ok. later I will create a Fiddle. I will accept your answer for now because .scrollTop with html,body works. I just remembered that some time ago I had some problems with forms in modal windows and then the only solution was to add second document statement. May it cause any problems?

Comment: Try targeting the exact form you are submiting and not everything in the document.